# Is that a new Diamond I see?

Tags: discussion

Who does [this guy](https://serverfault.com/users/48/sam) think he is with this new diamond next to his name?!

[image: profile for Sam at Server Fault, Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals]

Comment: Did he get his LART yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sam was the runner up in our 2011 moderation election, and has been with Server Fault since its very start. We felt we could use a little bit help keeping up with some of the moderator tasks so we made Sam a moderator.

Congrats Sam!

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I knew coming third would be useful one day! I look forward to helping out the guys who already do a fantastic job keeping this site focussed and clean (plus wielding that big mod hammer sounds like fun).

Comment: Ohhh, I see - so he gets to empty the bit bucket and mop up the slop then? (Congrats Sam. Also remember, new mods get a squeaky hammer!)

Comment: Congrats Sam and welcome!

Comment: Welcome to the fold. It get cozy sometimes.

Comment: Welcome to the glory and the um... well... you're a sysadmin, you're clearly not overly concerned with praise and recognition. ;)